# Prevent empty element from occupying space at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g334qt1y/2/
This happens in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Javascript libraries often insert empty nodes at the bottom of the page, such as the iframe in this example. I have tried to set it so it is takes no dimension. However it still creates one empty row right after the footer (in white).

Margins, paddings, line-heights have all been dealt with. However I can still see one thin white line at the bottom.

To qualify for bounty, I would like to know the **root CSS rule** causing this, and preferably a general way to disable that rule.

HTML:

```html
<header>
    header
</header>
<footer>
    footer
</footer>
<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="javascript:void(0)" name="test"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body, html {
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    display: block;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 1em;
}
footer {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1em;
}
iframe {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Did you read my updated answer?

Comment: yep it works! thanks. Just want to wait another day in case there are better solutions.

Comment: What attributes do these added elements share? From your comments, it sounds like it won't always be an iframe - you can potentially remove these elements by attribute or by a set of conditions. I typically find that empty spans are inserted as markers (REACT) or some of our backend developers leave empty paragraphs all over the show (poor form, I know), so I set up a list of :empty selectors. If you control the naming or another common attribute for these, you could use a combination of attributes. You'll have to state what the other elements are for us to provide you something more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Set your `iframe` to `display:none`, and you have that white space removed.</strike>

snippet below:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 1em;
}
footer {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1em;
}
iframe {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="javascript:void(0)" name="test"></iframe>
```

### UPDATE

For bounty purposes (as OP asked), here is an explanation:

> HTML `<iframe>` Element (or HTML inline frame element) is an inline
>   element. Therefore takes whitespace in your HTML into account.

So a solution is:

apply `display:block` to `iframe`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 1em;
}
footer {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1em;
}
iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="javascript:void(0)" name="test"></iframe>
```

Comment: However there are many of these dynamically inserted iframes. Sometimes setting it to none may have a negative impact. I want to find the root rule causing this.

Comment: Didn't understand your comment sorry. can you explain "However there are many of these dynamically inserted iframes" ?

Comment: My page has many JS libraries, which insert all kinds of containers at the bottom of the page. Rather than hiding them one by one, I want to know why it didn't work at the first place, and disable that root cause instead.

Answer (score 1):

Iframe does not take up any space here. The space you see under footer is caused by html/body line-height, you can set it to 0 to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks, I have set line-height to be zero. https://jsfiddle.net/g334qt1y/1/ 
However there is still a small gap at the bottom of footer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put 'margin :0' in footer class try to replace it with 'margin-bottom :-5px' you'll be able to remove the white space at the bottom of the page!! You can refer the following Fiddle [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/g334qt1y/4/)!

```
footer {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom : -5px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only dealing with empty `iframe`s and assuming that regular `iframe`s will have the source set to a URL and, if set as a node by a library, it always lists the source as `javascript:void(0)`, you can use that as an attribute selector ...

```
iframe[src="javascript:void(0)"]{
    display: none;
}
```

That's making a lot of assumptions though.

Updated your fiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/g334qt1y/6/)**

Comment: Already disregarded by OP, If you see OP's comment to my answer:)

Comment: @dippas you're right in saying that the OP already pointed out the potential side effect of this, but that would only be true/accurate if you were to set ALL iframes to display:none OR if you were specific about which one to set to display none. If some of my assumption is correct though and the source attribute is the common denominator, this could potentially be a viable solution. Then again: I cannot see a scenario in which your solution will have any negative side effect ... also: my answer is not exactly the same as your original answer.